# Flutter + Provider: How do I pass the value of the slider back to the provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Flutter 1.9.1
Provider 3.1.0

I am currently building my first app and I have decided to jump in on state management now as to not get to bogged down later on in my build.

I have set up a width_restriction_provider;

```
class WidthRestrictionProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _widthRestriction = 140;
  int get widthRestriction => _widthRestriction;

  set widthRestriction(int val) {
    _widthRestriction = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeWidthSlider(int newValue) {
    _widthRestriction = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

and this is my slider widget;

```
  class WidthSlider extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       final WidthRestrictionProvider widthRestrictionProvider =
        Provider.of<WidthRestrictionProvider>(context);
        return Container(
      child: Slider(
                      min: 140.0,
                      max: 420.0,
                      onChanged: () => widthRestrictionProvider.changeWidthSlider(newValue);
                    ),

    );
  }
}
```

I have tried many different ways but I keep running into problems along the way.

How do I successfully pass the new slider value back to the provider?

I am currently learning Flutter and Dart so I apologize if this question comes across as a little basic.

Comment: here changeWidthSlider(newValue),  what is newValue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using `statefulWidget` for the range slider. Hopefully it will work for you

```
class RangeSliderPricing extends StatefulWidget {
  const RangeSliderPricing({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RangeSliderPricingState createState() => _RangeSliderPricingState();
}

class _RangeSliderPricingState extends State<RangeSliderPricing> {
  RangeValues _currentRangeValues = RangeValues(20, 40);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RangeSlider(
      values: _currentRangeValues,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
      labels: RangeLabels(
        _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
        _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
      ),
      onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
        print('on change working $values');
        setState(() {
          _currentRangeValues = values;
        });

        context.read<ProductController>().fliterByPriceRange(
            priceStart: values.start.round().toDouble(),
            priceEnd: values.end.round().toDouble());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StatefullBuilder:

```
StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, setState) {
    return Slider(
      value: myProvider.sliderValue,
      onChanged: ((double value) {
        setState(() => myProvider.sliderValue = value);
      }),
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
    );    
  },
),
```